# What books are appropriate candidates to be recorded in the 'Reading' section of the CV?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Stack Overflow Careers allows you to enter books that you've read by either title, author, or ISBN. These books are published on your CV for anyone to see.

I'm sure we've all read a lot of books, and some of us could enter hundreds or even thousands of books in this section, but I don't think that entering any old book will enhance your CV (I'm sure we've all read a book where after putting it down, we wished we had our time back).

So, which, if any of the following categories are good candidates to have listed?

- Textbooks/certification books (on database design, algorithms, mathematics, or operating systems)
- Favorite books among IT folks (*1984*, *Animal Farm*, *Dune*, *Fahrenheit 451*)
- Random books of fiction I enjoyed (*The Truth*, or *Going Postal* by Terry Pratchett, books on theology or history)
- None at all (Do books even have a place on a CV?)

Besides "whatever you would like to include!", what books should I include to enhance my CV?

Comment: I wouldn't put "Books read" on a CV at all. I'd only list books that I had some contribution to - authored, technically reviewed, credited in, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the jobs portion is to find a job, and your CV is basically your resume to find a job.  Then consider adding books which you feel would add value to you obtaining a job.

For instance, consider you are looking to join a job that involves a lot of scrum and team work it would be great to read the book [Team Geek](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449302440).  This book is excellent in learning how to work with people and the psychology of people.  People are strange monsters, especially in the workplace.  Behind the work of people is personal lives, beliefs, attitudes, etc.  You need to not only know how to work with them but react to them.  So adding this book to your CV will help a potential employer stop and say look he's reading a book on exactly what we like - team work.

Or maybe you are interviewing with Microsoft to help build the next version of C#.  Adding the book [CLR via C#](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735627045) will help microsoft see that you are a serious candidate who likes to understand the internals of C#.

Obviously you should not add books that you don't think will help you find a career.  For instance, do you really need to add the book about [Stephen Curry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1499118090) if you aren't applying for a basketball position.

You want to supplement your work experience and your skills with books related to both of those.  You can include some off topic stuff if you want to discuss a hobby, for instance maybe you have a knack for algorithms and you spend some nights tinkering with how to write a better sorting algorithm. I'm certain adding a few algo books would be in your favor.  Besides it could be additional talk during the interview..."So gkubed, I see you had 3 algo books in your cv, why algo books"..."Well I love algos because...".  This could be a nice little talk about your hobbies.

Comment: Thank you - I'll revise my book selection accordingly. I imagine seven books is a good number to keep down there - enough to show you're interested but not enough to have people flipping through your library.

Comment: You don't want too many as that could cause your cv to be several pages long.  Keep it simple 3-5 is enough.